# IE only prints the first page in an IFrame

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, printing

I see lots of questions about printing iframes with JavaScript, but nothing related to my issue. I have an HTML document that is very odd. It contains JavaScript inside that sets up an inner IFrame when it opens and writes data to it. Yes, this is odd, but I'm stuck with it.

If I open this HTML file locally, Chrome prints the document. Both pages. IE on the other hand shows two pages in the print preview. The first page is as expected, and the second page is blank.

Why is this not working? Any ideas? I'm sorry to post this as a programming question; but it's the best fit. If the HTML/JavaScript can be modified in any way to make this work, that would make it a programming question I guess!

You can view the file and download it here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x4u0VrMBvwkC2vOjKXReF_CdE5vRjldm-WYsAgXJMc4

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Comment: I spent weeks to rework the entire project. I no longer have an IFrame being used. I don't think there's a way around this. Just can't use IE.

Comment: @Paul Can you please update your question posting your file here.

Comment: I updated the link to a newer file. The system we were using that generated these things was archaic and was entirely rewritten. So this is not a problem for me anymore. But you can still reproduce this by downloading that `html` file and opening it in IE and running print preview.